# Is binary search "commutative"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

**BACKGROUND**

I have two instruments, call then `1` and `2`, which receive the signal produced by a third, nearby transmitter. This transmitter has a known period, `T`. These instruments produce time series, where each timestamp is the current time according to the instrument clock when a signal was detected.

I know that the clock in instrument `3` has some slow drift, relative to instrument `1`, which has caused a time offset. My goal is to determine the size of this drift.

I wrote the code below to achieve this. All I've done is to iterate through the timestamps produced by one station, and search for the nearest timestamp produced by the remaining station. Since the pulser period is on the order of seconds, and the offset at most a fraction of a second, this should give the right "match". I wrote a very simple binary search function (`search()`) to find the closest match.

Strangely, the offset determine by iterating through instrument `1`'s timestamps and searching instrument `2`'s gives a different offset than the reverse (loops #1 and #2, respectively). If I search a vector `A` for the nearest match to some value in `B`, then shouldn't searching `B` for the nearest match to that match give the original value?

I'm very likely making some dumb mistake, but try as I might I cannot determine what I've done wrong.

**My Code**

```
double search(std::vector<double> &vec, double value){
    
    auto it = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), value);
    if(it == vec.end()) return vec.back();

    auto found = *it;

    if(it != vec.begin()){

        if(std::abs(value - *(--it)) <  std::abs(value - found)){
            found = *(--it);
        }

    }

    return found;

}

int main(){

    /*****GET DATA*****/
    ROOT::RDataFrame data1("/path/to/file");
    ROOT::RDataFrame data2("/path/to/file");

    auto timestamps1 = *(data1.Take<double>("timestamps"));
    auto timestamps2 = *(data2.Take<double>("timestamps"));

    TH1 *histo1 = new TH1D("histo","histo1",1000,-5,5);
    TH1 *histo2 = new TH1D("histo","histo2",1000,-5,5);

    /*****PERFORM SEARCH*****/
    for(auto& t: timestamps1){ // LOOP # 1
 
        histo1->Fill(search(timestamps2, t) - t); 

    }

    for(auto& t: timestamps2){ // LOOP # 2
 
        histo2->Fill(search(timestamps1, t) - t); 

    }

    /*****DRAW HISTOGRAMS*****/
    histo1->Draw();
    histo2->Draw();

}
```

Comment: `search` can decrement `it` twice, which seems to be unintended. Also, the two search loops search for values in the same timestamp array as you're iterating over.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I don't see how `search` can decrement `it` twice. Could you elaborate?

Comment: In the `if(std::abs(value - *(--it))` statement, it is decremented once. Then the body of the if (`found = *(--it);`) decrements `it` a second time. So `found` will have a different value than used in the comparison, and you potentially dereference an invalid iterator.

Answer (score 2):

> If I search a vector A for the nearest match to some value in B, then shouldn't searching B for the nearest match to that match give the original value?

Not necessarily, no.

Consider the following two vectors:

```
A: 0 3 8 9 10
B: 2 5 6 9 11
```

Then if I search A for the nearest match to (say) 5, I get 3.

If I then search B for the nearest match to 3, I get 2.

So if you're relying on this, you'll have to look for an alternative solution.